Golang connecting with Oracle Database TNS Adaptor Error
I was trying to establish a connection with the remote Oracle Database via GOLANG. I used the "godror" library but it came out with the error of "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error". I'd like to know what's the problem.
Here's the code that I used:
db, err:= sql.Open("godror",user = "username" password = "password" connectString = "hostname:port/service_name")
The username, password and connectString that I used for GOLANG is the same that I'm using with the sqldeveloper for connecting to the database. No such "TNS Protocol Adaptor Error" issue happened.
I thought that maybe was the oracle_home/tns_admin environment problem, but it still failed after configuring those 2 environment path.

You will get down votes quickly if you don't supply more information details about your client and server config and OS.

I‘m able to use SQL/PLUS to connect to the destination database, but unable to build the connection via GOLANG.

Are you sure that you're specifying the proper service_name in the connectString?  I only ask because you mentioned the TNS_ADMIN environment variable, which means you that your sqlplus or SQL*Developer might be looking up the connection details via a TNS alias in a tnsnames.ora file.  If that's the case, be sure that you're using the actual service_name and not the TNS alias name.  For example, if sqlplus someuser@somedb is working, look up somedb in your tnsnames.ora file and confirm that whatever service_name it references is the one you're using in the connectString.

Review the godror connection syntax doc: https://godror.github.io/godror/doc/connection.html
